# How to prevent the Apple Watch from going to sleep?

Tags: xcode, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

We are working on an Apple Watch project, but the watch goes to sleep if uninterrupted with.

Is there any way to prevent it from going to sleep?

Comment: Any hack like that would drain the precious battery power of the watch, so I hope that Apple makes sure it's not available to application programmers.

Comment: You can increase the wake time time to 70 seconds, for me that's more then I need.
From the phone acces
Watch->General->Wake Screen-> (select wake for 70s)

Answer (score 6):

As of my knowledge and other searches on this topic, at the moment is no `api` available to enable or even disable sleep mode for Apple Watch programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

**No-Sleep API**

Currently, there is no API to disable Apple Watch from going to sleep.

You may wait until watchOS 3.

**Changing Sleep Time By User**

Any user can go to this path:

> Settings -> General -> Wake Screen

And set the time to a long time.

Unfortunately, only the user can change this and there is no way to do it programmatically.

NOTE: If you want the screen to resume your activity after waking up, you should ask user to do so here:

> Settings -> General -> Wake Screen -> Resume Last Activity

Note that according to Owen, keeping the watch awake would kill the battery quickly.

**Conclusion**

1- No API is set.

2- User can change sleep time.

3- User can select to resume last activity when the Apple Watch wakes up.

Comment: Is this possible in WatchOS 4?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the power requirements, keeping the watch awake would kill the battery quickly.  However, you may be concerned that when the watch does go to sleep, it doesn't re-wake to your app.  This can be remedied at the user level, on your iOS device using the Watch App, using General->Wake Screen-> and checking "Resume Last Activity"