# Keeping Apple Watch Awake for more than 70 seconds (watchOS 3)

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-3

Is there any way to keep an Apple Watch awake for more than 70 seconds? I understand the purpose of turning off the face to save battery life but I'm trying to sample motion data continuously for about 3 minutes and the sampling is interrupted as soon as the face turns off. I've set the watch to stay awake for 70 seconds every time I tap it, but is there any way to prevent it from turning off for > 3 minutes? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393307/how-to-prevent-the-apple-watch-from-going-to-sleep) post from Feb. of 2016 but haven't found any updates confirming or denying the possibility of preventing the watch face from sleeping in watchOS 3.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking at sampling motion data like the accelerometer or gyroscope, you can create a HKWorkout Session that will keep your app running in the background. While your Watch face will still eventually turn off without tapping, you will still continue to be able to keep sampling your motion data. Note that only one HKWorkout Session can be run at a time. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for the input and I'll test it out! Do you know if Apple allows the use of the HKWorkoutsession for purposes like this? We'd like to eventually get the application onto the App Store but would like to make sure we are in compliance with the requirements set forth by Apple.

Comment: No problem, I hope it helps you! I can't say for certain if Apple would approve an App that does this on the App Store, but that's what I would do and in my opinion I think that they would- especially if the sampling you're doing is only about three minutes and even more so if it has something to do with health, wellness, or fitness.